# long int not being declared properly [C++]

Tags: c++

Here's the piece of code

```
long int lValue = 9999999999999;
cout << lValue << endl;
```

I am running it on Eclipse IDE for C/C++, using MinGW compiler.

I have include the `#include <limits.h>` properly and other sort of short and unsigned int are being compiled and showing a value properly.

But while running this long int value, I am getting the following value.
1316134911 instead of the original value, I tried it with different values but each time it's getting a random value. Any more details required? let me know, thanks in advance!

Comment: On that platform `long int` is the same as `int`.  You need `long long` ... `9999999999999LL`  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586118/what-is-the-suffix-used-for-long-long-constants

Comment: Following JSF's comment about platform, it works on coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02642435a6f6e598 (gcc), and http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8345410f21e2c7b4 (clang)

Comment: @JSF Thanks alot mate, that worked completely fine for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `long long` if you want to store 64 bits (and you do).

```
    const auto lValue = 9999999999999LL;
```

or

```
    long long lValue = 9999999999999LL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `L` to the end of your 9's.

Comment: The same value is being generated.

Comment: @Saw do you have any optimization flags enabled when compiling?

Comment: @Freddy none as of I know, I am new to Eclipse. Can you please route me to the location on how I can find this optimization flags?

Comment: `LL` will be a `long long`, which is always at least 64 bits. `L` is `long` which is 64 bits on Linux but 32 bits on Windows.

Comment: Why can't we all just get a `long`?

Comment: Adding `L` won't make this value fit in a `long`. It's too big.